# How to insert the product of two variables into a table if one of them is stored in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, variables, insert

Good evening everybody.

Here is my issue:

I have a list of variables which is defined by an 'extract' command. They are numeric values that represent the number of wooden boards produced in a sawmill.

Another list of variables is stored in an SQL table. They represent the volume coefficients that come from the different sizes of lumber produced.

The idea is that a person could enter the number of boards of a certain size in an input field. The two numbers are then multiplied by each other to result in a general volume of lumber produced and are to be inserted into an SQL table. 
The specification table containing the volumes also contains the variable names for the amount, if needed.

There needs to be some kind of automated loop that cycles all the variables carrying numeric values for the number of boards produced because new specifications can be added anytime that will create new variables for the amount.

I think I want to make work something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Rspecs";
$result = mysql_query($query);


 while( ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)))
{

    $conn->exec("INSERT INTO Eprocessing (date, amount, product, sort, notes, type, optype) 
    VALUES 
    ('$date', '$amount*.$row['volume'].', '.$row['product'].', '0-3', '$notes', '$type', 'Processing')");


}
```

This obviously highly incorrect syntax represents what I want to do mostly. Please help me bringing this into a correct form.
thanks to everybody in advance.

```
$conn->exec("INSERT INTO Eprocessing 
(date, amount, product, sort, notes, type, optype) 
VALUES  
('$date', '.$row['volume']. * $v22703', '$type', '0-3', '$notes', '$type', 'Processing')
('$date', '.$row['volume']. * $v291453', '$type', '0-3', '$notes', '$type', 'Processing')
('$date', '.$row['volume']. * $v291003', '$type', '0-3', '$notes', '$type', 'Processing')");
```

Comment: tried your own code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need first query and loop, just this simple:

```
$conn->exec("INSERT INTO Eprocessing (date, amount, product, sort, notes, type, optype) 
SELECT '$date', 
       ($amount * rs.volume), 
       rs.product,
       '0-3', 
       '$notes', 
       '$type', 
       'Processing'
FROM Rspecs rs;");
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Could you however explain how this rs.volume and Rspecs rs are supposed to work? Besause this code returns a Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064.

Comment: Alright, I understood it so far. But there's another problem: I made a little mistake in my question: there is no $amount variable. There are multiple amounts to be entered simultaneously and the all have different input field names. They are stored in variables by extract($_POST, EXTR_SKIP); Also they are stored in the Rspecs table. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: show the full fragment of your current code. do you have something?

Comment: I added what I am trying to do at the very bottom of my initial question. There needs to be an arithmetic operation that multiplies the volume by the amount produced. And there needs to be an automation that cycles through all the variables that represent the amount of the respective wooden boards produced. Those are transferred through input fields and POST method. I could do this for each variable that starts with a '$v..' but how do I get the multiplication with the volumes working?

Comment: No you did almost nothing. Your code fragment is too small. It can not explain the logic flow of your application, and nobody can get where all those variables come from. and there is no information about how many times you have to loop your query. you provided very few information.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors. When you are trying to cancatenate a variable which is an array index, you should wrap with `{}`

so your query should look like this,

```
$amt = $amount * $row['volume'] ;
$conn->exec("INSERT INTO Eprocessing (date, amount, product, sort, notes, type, optype) VALUES  ('$date', ' $amt', '{$row['product']}' , '0-3', '$notes', '$type', 'Processing')");
```

Comment: Thanks for help. However, can't make this work - returns the no password error.

Comment: Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'//iphidden//' (using password: NO) in //address hidden//proc_processing.php on line 24

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in //address hidden//proc_processing.php on line 24

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in //address hidden//proc_processing.php on line 27

this occurs when I am trying to use {} expressions inside the SQL statement

Comment: $query = "SELECT speccode FROM Rspecs";
$result = mysql_query($query);


 while( ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)))
{
 
$amt = $amount * $row['volume'] ;
$conn->exec("INSERT INTO Eprocessing (date, amount, product, sort, notes, type, optype) VALUES  ('$date', ' $amt', '{$row['speccode']}' , '0-3', '$notes', '$type', 'Processing')");

}     thats what im trying to use, like you said

Comment: No. The PDO connection works fine. But when i add this '{$row['speccode']}' ,  it gives me the no password error.